# Subscribe button not sending notification of a new subscriber to my email

Tags: facebook, button, subscribe

When users press the subscribe button on my website (as new subscribers) it becomes grey but I'm not getting any notification message to my Email.
The page is: http://www.en4u.co.il

This is my code:

iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/subscribe.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fezraelias&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&font&width=450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;" allowTransparency="true">

Where is the error?
Thanks
Gal Cahana

Comment: Why would it send you an email? Does it usually send you an email for new subscribers?

Comment: Yes it does. If a subscriber is subscribing on Facebook directly.

Comment: Have you changed your notification settings recently? Maybe the subscribe notification is turned off: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=Facebook&view

Comment: No. Without subscribe notification turned on you are not able to present the subscribe button in your website.